# jedi support in spyder 4

Tags: python, spyder

I updated to Spyder 4 (4.0.0?) to get the latest and greatest features. At this time I found out that Spyder now has the option of using Kite for autocompletion. After trying Kite for a bit I wanted to revert back to the previous autocompletion setup. I thought this was possible by unchecking to use Kite in the preferences, but then autocompletion seemed to be completely broken.

In conda I noticed my current version of Jedi was out of date, and I upgraded to the newest version. In the process I noticed that conda said it needed to downgrade Spyder for the Jedi upgrade. This gives me the impression that Spyder 4 just doesn't support Jedi. Is that the case?

Comment: do you have 'enable fallback completions' toggle on? (just beneath the Kite toggle.  Also .... conda update .... --no-pin --dry-run  where ... is the package you want to install.  It will then give you a sense if things will go bad by doing an update

Comment: Yes, I enabled the fallback but code completion was not working like it had in Spyder 3. Thanks for the tip on the conda update script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Spyder 4.0.0 and 4.0.1 only work with Jedi **0.14.1**. Newer nor older versions are supported, so be sure to have that exact version installed.

By the way, although not required, Kite completions are better for scientific packages than Jedi ones.

Comment: Thanks Carlos for the response and for all of your work on Spyder. I think I had 0.14.2 installed. I saw the note about Kite and packages like numpy. In retrospect I think the problem was that I had not annotated my class variables properly. I'll probably try and go back and use Spyder with Kite with class variable annotations in place.